# "Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'" in build with cordova-electron and serialport.io

Tags: javascript, cordova, electron, serial-port, node-serialport

#### Problem

Hello, my problem is when I include the library SerialPort.io in my cordova-electron projet, build crashe on windows 10 , window 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.

#### What is expected to happen?

Build launch and I can use serial port.

#### What does actually happen?

Build don't launch and error is displayed.

### Information

I am trying to use the serial port library on cordova-electron.
When i use
`cordova run electron --nobuild` , this work perfectly and the application is launch.
When i want to do the build, I use
`cordova build android`and there are no errors.
But when I launch the build , this error is displayed :

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'
Require stack:
- /pathToMyProject/cordova/platforms/electron/build/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/cdv-electron-main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.n._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:245:1128)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:737:27)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/pathToMyProject/cordova/platforms/electron/build/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/cdv-electron-main.js:27:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1113:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
```

The line "cdv-electron-main.js:27:24" is

```
const { SerialPort } = require("serialport");
```

I have the same issue in Windows 10, Windows 11 and Ubuntu22.04.

#### Steps to reproduce  :

Create a projet with cordova-electron

```
npm i -g cordova
cordova create sampleApp
cd sampleApp
cordova platform add electron
```

Add serialport

```
npm i serialport
```

Update sampleApp/platforms/electron/platform_www

```
#Add this in top of file
const { SerialPort } = require("serialport");
#And after all the const declarations, add this
console.log("hello serialport : " , SerialPort);
```

Try it with

```
cordova run electron --nobuild
```

That work and the console.log is make.

Build the project with

```
cordova build electron
```

There are no errors

But when you try to open the executable (for exemple in window, it is
in /sampleApp/platforms/electron/build/win-unpacked/HelloCordova.exe, this error message is displayed

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'
Require stack:
- /pathToMyProject/cordova/platforms/electron/build/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/cdv-electron-main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.n._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:245:1128)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:737:27)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/pathToMyProject/cordova/platforms/electron/build/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/cdv-electron-main.js:27:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1113:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
```

#### Environment, Platform, Device

Ubuntu 22.04

#### Version information

serialport : 12.0.0
Ubuntu : 22.04
cordova-electron : 3.1.0
cordova : 12.0.0
react:18.2.0

#### Links to documentation

[Documentation cordova-electron](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/guide/platforms/electron/index.html#how-to-support-nodejs-and-electron-apis)  
[Documentation SerialPort.io](https://serialport.io/)

Comment: Exact same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes and no.
I solve it by use directly electron instead of cordova-electron for making application for windows.
But now, i have to create 32bits installer for windows, and i have the same problem with electron, with the library serial port ...

If you have to make 64bits installer for window, I recommend you to use electron directly with electron-builder, instead of electron-cordova.

Comment: I (finally) discovered my problem was I'd been adding packages to package.json in my project's root directory, when in fact they needed to be added to <project root>/platforms/electron/package.json.